# Not Able to render new Component on link change

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router, router

Actually when ever a person click's on Sign in Button the link change but the component on that page does not renders

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Join} />
      <Route path="/call" exact component={Call} />

  </Switch>
);

export default App;
```

Join.js

```
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div><input id="room" placeholder="room name" onChange={(event)=>setRoom(event.target.value)}></input></div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                <Link onClick={event => (!room) ? event.preventDefault() : null} to={`/call?room=${room}`}>
                  <button className="button mt-20" type="submit" onClick={run}>Sign In</button>
                </Link>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }


export default Join;
```

Call.js

```
const Call = () => {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>jhjcjc</h1>
            </div>
        );

}

export default Call;
```

Please look over this error many developer's are facing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Join` component, there is no need to wrap `Link` in a `BrowserRouter`. Check out the working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-framework-s61lj?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Ohh , Thanks for the help it worked for me. Btw can you tell the reason why not wrap ```Link``` with  ```BrowserRouter```

Comment: Sure, since you have wrapped your entire app inside the router, all the route updates are now handled automatically. All you have to do now is point to any given route using the `Link` component. BTW, since you found the answer helpful, can you please accept it. Thanks!